# Converting string with many leading zeros to decimal

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, leading-zero

How can I convert string which looks like this:

```
0005.47
```

to decimal value `5.47`.

This value is kept in `newStringArray[1]` so I did this: `Convert.ToDecimal(newStringArray[1])`

But as a result I got this value : `547`

What's the point here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your culture settings think that a point is not the decimal separator but the thousands separator.

You need to pass the information about the culture you want to use to Convert.ToDecimal. It can be done passing the [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netcore-3.1) property to inform the converter to use the proper decimal symbol when converting.

```
string test = "0005.47";
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(test, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```